# JUnit testing framework

Tags: junit

I am trying to learn more about JUnit as a potential testing framework as my project gets too complicated. I don't understand how it works though. Is there a recommendation of a simple example of JUnit testing to show how it works for a newbie?

Comment: Did you google "Junit Tutorial"? https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#q=junit+tutorial

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit is Java's version of unit testing. The idea of unit testing is to test individual components of the project, rather than the workflow, to ensure all pieces are working by themselves. Then, if the design itself is correct, the project will ideally be correct as well. It also helps provide stability in future updates.

For effective JUnit testing, you should make use of Assertions (provided by JUnit), as well as things like Spying, Mocking, and Verifying (provided by a tool like Mockito or EasyMock). Take a look at those and see why they are useful.

For a good example - [this is the first result](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html) in googling "JUnit tutorial". There's tons of resources out there about unit testing, just google around